# how to save data of ckeditor in cakephp 2.7.5

Tags: jquery, cakephp, ckeditor

i have problem to saving textarea of ckeditor in cakephp 2.7.5

i'm working to edit content of drop down into editor

but now how to save this field data name attribute is already occupied 
here html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group last">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="editor1"  rows="6" data-error-container="#editor2_error">

                </textarea>
                <div id="editor2_error"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnAddToken').click(function () {
            var tokenValue = $('#token').val();
            var data = "#" + tokenValue + "#";
            if (tokenValue != '') {
                CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(data);
                /*tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, );*/
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "_but now how to save this field data name attribute is already occupied here_" I don't think anyone is able to figure out what you mean by this. Please rephrase your question to make the actual problem that you are facing more clear. A code example of the actual saving problem, with a proper explanation of what exactly doesn't work why exactly, may help too.

Comment: i want to save that field